# Any way to get the cost per file on s3 or cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a small static site hosted on s3, served through cloudfront. I've been trying to reduce the costs but now I'm at a point that I really just need to know which files are getting downloaded the most. How can I figure that out?

Thanks.

Comment: How about the [CloudFront Popular Objects Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/popular-objects-report.html)?

Comment: I think that might actually work, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your CloudFront distribution statistics. In the AWS Management Console, go to CloudFront, and select "Popular Objects" from the left navigation panel.

It will show you the the following statistsics:

- requested URL (into CloudFront)
- whether it was a cache hit or miss,
- bytes for misses (this tells you how many bytes are read from your origin)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed. Just trying to understand the numbers, am I charged for `bytes from misses` or `total bytes` or both?

Comment: You'll be charged on many fronts. You're charged for outgoing to internet (total bytes), outgoing to origin (not mentioned), per 10,000 requests, and S3 data out (bytes from misses).

Comment: Ok, thank you, this is really eye opening. I thought only my images were using a lot of data but the html and javascript is pretty large as well. Guess I'll have to see if minify will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable analytics for the bucket (under Management tab), which will help you understand if any files can be moved for example to Infrequent Access storage class.

If you want to have the exact access logs, you could also enable [Access Logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out.